# Windows 10 1903 cannot run exe from network share

Tags: windows

common problem, clean windows 10 - cannot start exe from network share; exe tested from server that is in the same AD in which laptop is, also from another share (openmediavault)

I'm out of ideas, tried many solutions from the net.

Problem is similar to this:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2193810-sporadically-unable-to-run-exe-from-network-share-windows-10

[image]

Comment: Please translate the error dialog to English.

Comment: The share must be added to trusted locations list. If not then the file is locked (similar to common "this file was downloaded from Internet...") and so cannot be executed.

Comment: @harrymc - Windows cannot access the exe... contact winh administrator...

Comment: And as a standard question got downvote without a single word of explanation why it was downvoted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: As Akina suggested, I've added the smb server address to the Trusted Locations in Internet Options, and it worked (at least for the share from server which is in AD, don't work for openmediavault 4.x - smb version issue? idk)

Comment: So set this as solution.

Answer (score -1):

smb.conf execute default is no, so set for selected share
in OMV Services/SMB-CIFS/Share/Edit/Extra options:

```
acl allow execute always = true
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).